# Weird GET requests for another website on my express server?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just a student trying to host my assignment online.

I've noticed I'm getting malicious POST requests that seem to be being handled by lusca's csrf but I'm not 100% sure.
But whats puzzling me more is the successful GET requests to an external website.

[image: putty image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. I really don't want my server getting defaced when I'm trying to do a presentation in a couple of months.

I'm also redirecting all port 80 traffic to the actual port the server is hosted on because its not running on root.

Comment: Are the requests directed to your domain? Maybe this is from some older domain taht used to be hosted on your server/IP.